# JPA not taking update into account within single Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Within a transactional service method, I loop on querying a database to get the first 10 of entity A with a criteria.

I update each A entity from the list so that they don't match the criteria anymore, and call a flush() to make sure changes are made.

The second call to the query within the loop returns the exact same set of A entities.

Why isn't the flushed change on the entities taken into account?

I'm using JPA 2.0 with Hibernate 4.1.7.
The same process with Hibernate only seems to be working.
I've turned off the second level cache and the query cache, to no avail.

I'm using a rather plain configuration, JpaTransactionManager, Spring over JPA over Hibernate. Main method annotated with @Transactional.

The code would be something like this:

```
do {
    modelList = exportContributionDao.getContributionListToExport(10);
    for (M m : modelList) {
        //export m to a file
    m. (false);
    super.flush();
    }
} while (modelList.size() == 10);
```

With each iteration of the loop, the Dao method always return the same 10 results, JPA not taking into account  the updated 'isToBeExported' attribute.

I'm not trying to solve a problem, rather I want to understand why JPA is not behaving as expected here.
I expect this to be a 'classic' problem. 
No doubt it would be solved if the Transaction would be commited at each iteration.

ASAIK, the cache L1, i.e. the Session with Hibernate as the underlying JPA provider, should be up to date, and the second iteration query should take into account the updated Entities, even though the changes haven't been persisted yet.
So my question is: why isn't it the case? Misconfiguration or know behavior?

Comment: Need a lot more information here. Where's your SSCCE containing code loop, instantiation of your entity manager, annotated portions of your entity classes? Also, include wether your using CMT or not, and if you have explicitly defined a lock mode in your query. For extra points include *relevant* portions of your database schema.

Comment: Are you looking up the A entities in the same transaction? Are the As part of a relationship?

Comment: Sorry for not provided a SSCCE, I've updated the original post. Everything is happening in a single transaction. A is not part of a relationship, at least it's not in use within the query.

Answer (score 1):

Flush does not necessarily commit the changes on the database. What do you want to achieve? From what I understand you do s.th. like:

1. Loop about entities
2. Within the loop, change the entity
3. Call 'flush' on the entity
4. Read the entity back again
5. You wonder why the data did not change on the database?

If this is correct, why do you re-read the changes and just don't work with the elements? After leaving the transaction, the changes will be automagically made persistent.

Comment: This was the original code a developer in our team commited. This wasn't a good design, it has been changed and resolved already.

For the sake of understanding JPA, I'm trying to to make sense whether this should be working or whether it is an expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely be working.

This is a configuration problem on our part.

Apologies for the question, it was pretty hard to spot the reason on our part, but I hope the answer will at least be useful to some:

JPA definitely takes into account changes made on entities within a single transaction.